# Как отправить длинный json запрос

Tags: python, json, curl, запрос, flask

Есть REST API сервис на python и flask. Пытаюсь отправить длинный запрос (где в структуре json 200.000 символов):

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"ЗДЕСЬ 200.000 СИМВОЛОВ"}' http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/curl: Argument list too long
```

Может для это можно использовать не curl, а с помощью чего-то другого отправить запрос

Как решить такую задачу

Comment: Записать строку в файл и запускать curl с параметром - брать данные для post из этого файла?

Comment: @Jigius, да, для POST

Comment: попробуйте через файл, как я написал ранее. Это у меня был вариант-предложение, чтобы решить вашу проблему ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть три способа — быстрый, допустимый и идеологически верный:

1. Быстрый — увеличить лимит на размер тела запроса. Будет значительный рост потребления памяти на запрос. Не рекомендую в качестве постоянного решения.

```py
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024  # размер в байтах
```

2. Допустимый, вам нужно часто создавать подобные объекты и HTTP — единственный доступный вам протокол. Пересмотрите api и отправляйте форму с файлом json с типом `multipart/form-data`. Это позволит отправлять данные большего размера, но требуется поддержка с стороны веб-сервера. Будет значительный рост потребления памяти на запрос.

```py
@app.route('/instance', methods=['POST'])
def create_instance():
    raw_data = request.form.get('data')
    instance = Instance(**json.loads(raw_data))
    return jsonify(instance)
```

```bsh
curl -X POST -F 'data=@path/to/local/file.json' "http://localhost:5000/instance"
```

3. Идеологически верный — пересмотреть работу с API. Сделайте два отдельных ресурса, один из - которых создает сущность, а второй — наполняет её содержимым. Придется делать значительно больше запросов.

```py
# Псевдокод

@app.route('/instance', methods=['POST'])
def create_instance():
    instance = Instance(**request.json())
    return jsonify(instance)


@app.route('/instance-content/<instance_id>', methods=['POST'])
def fill_instance(instance_id):
    instance = Instance.query().filter(Instance.id==instance_id).one_or_none()
    
    if not instance:
        raise abort(404)

    instance.append_content(**request.json())
    instance.save()

    return None, 204
```

Также, можно обрабатывать PATCH-запросы, чтобы частично обновлять данные.

P.S.: Используйте толстые модели, тонкие контроллеры и глупые представления.